# Unable to animate the position of an image in a WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, animation, storyboard

Ok so I have a Class that is created by the default window's .vb script.
This class creates a player which has some basic movement controls as well as some gravity.
The player is made up of an image and a couple other bits and is meant to be moved around by a Storyboard using DoubleAnimations.

The problem is, I can't seem to get the DoubleAnimations to work correctly no matter how many different methods I try to make it work.

I cut down the code to more digestible bits which focus on the bits that are actually important.

```
    Dim Timer As System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer = New System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, Application.Current.Dispatcher)
    Public PlayerVisualInstance As Image
    Public MainWindowClass As MainWindow

    Public XPositionMoving As Boolean = False
    Public YPositionMoving As Boolean = False
    Public Shared TweenRequests As String() = New String(8) {"0", "0", "0", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "0", "0", "0"}
    Public WithEvents TweenStoryboard As Storyboard = New Storyboard
    Public VisualInstanceTransformGroup As New TransformGroup
    Public VisualInstanceTranslateTransform As New TranslateTransform
    Public Shared TweenShouldRun As Boolean = False
    Public Shared TweenDone As Boolean = True
    Public Shared TweenDebounce As Boolean = False

    Public Sub New()
        AddHandler Timer.Tick, AddressOf Timer_Tick
        Timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)
        Timer.Start()
        PlayerVisualInstance = New Image
        PlayerVisualInstance.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left
        PlayerVisualInstance.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top
        PlayerVisualInstance.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform
        PlayerVisualInstance.StretchDirection = StretchDirection.Both
        PlayerVisualInstance.SnapsToDevicePixels = True
        VisualInstanceTransformGroup.Children.Add(VisualInstanceTranslateTransform)
        PlayerVisualInstance.RenderTransform = VisualInstanceTransformGroup
    End Sub

    Public Sub CharacterProcessing()
        'tons and tons of processing bits which aren't relevant here
        TweenStuff()
    End Sub

    Private Sub StoryboardCompletion() Handles TweenStoryboard.Completed
        TweenDone = True
        'TweenDebounce = False
        'like this just to ensure that a tween only runs once for testing
        XPositionMoving = False
        YPositionMoving = False
    End Sub

    Public Sub TweenStuff()
        If TweenShouldRun = True Then
            TweenShouldRun = False

            Dim XConvert As Decimal = CType(TweenRequests(0), Decimal)
            Dim YConvert As Decimal = CType(TweenRequests(1), Decimal)
            Dim XAmountConvert As Decimal = CType(TweenRequests(6), Decimal)
            Dim YAmountConvert As Decimal = CType(TweenRequests(7), Decimal)

            Dim TweenAnimationX As DoubleAnimation = New DoubleAnimation()
            Dim TweenAnimationY As DoubleAnimation = New DoubleAnimation()
            TweenAnimationX.From = VisualInstanceTranslateTransform.X
            TweenAnimationX.To = XConvert
            TweenAnimationY.From = VisualInstanceTranslateTransform.Y
            TweenAnimationY.To = YConvert
            TweenAnimationX.Duration = New Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(XAmountConvert))
            TweenAnimationY.Duration = New Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(YAmountConvert))
            Storyboard.SetTarget(TweenAnimationX, PlayerVisualInstance)
            Storyboard.SetTarget(TweenAnimationY, PlayerVisualInstance)
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(TweenAnimationX, New PropertyPath(VisualInstanceTranslateTransform.X))
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(TweenAnimationY, New PropertyPath(VisualInstanceTranslateTransform.Y))
            TweenStoryboard.Children.Add(TweenAnimationX)
            TweenStoryboard.Children.Add(TweenAnimationY)
            TweenStoryboard.Begin()
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        CharacterProcessing()
    End Sub
```

To give some details, TweenRequests contains a series of values to use in the tweens, the primarily used ones being 0,1,6 and 7 which are the X and Y end points and duration times for each respectively.

Outside of the class, some values are set to the player that can't be set immediately from the Sub New(), this includes running RegisterName on the TranslateTransform.

A tick statement is used to run through everything and to constantly keep the storyboard stuff up to date. There is probably a more optimised way to do this but it works.

The part that doesn't work however is the storyboard animation itself.

I have tried various methods such as swapping to ThicknessAnimations, setting different properties in SetTargetProperty and experimenting with TranslateTransforms. None of these methods worked properly minus one instance where it slightly worked but then broke immediately and didn't show results the next time I compiled. On all of these times it sometimes didn't even error at all but didn't have any visible impact on things ( even though I proved through debugging that the storyboard does play through properly ) or it threw some kind of error at the Storyboard.SetTargetProperty() section, always relating to the PropertyPath.

I'm at a bit of a loss of things to try here so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)` will not work. DispatcherTimer is not able to execute its Tick handler at a rate of 1 kHz. Try an interval of 20 ms or so.